# Could $\nu_e+p\rightarrow e^-+\pi^++p$ occur via the weak interaction? If so, how would be the Feynman diagram?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, weak-interaction

I checked if the reaction conservate baryon number, charge and leptonic number and it seems like it does. But I tried to draw the Feynman diagram and I don't understand how the proton interact, so maybe the reaction can't occur? Or is something about the Feynman diagrams that I still don't understand?

I'm new to Feynman diagrams, so any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: Knowing the right vocabulary help. A quick internet search of *"weak associated production"* yields a bunch of links [going back to at least 1975](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.12.2049). Now, "associated production" is generally about the production of *strangeness* (in both the altered baryon and the meson), but the the diagrams for the production of un-strange mesons look the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem.

The neutrino emits a virtual $W^+$ and thereby turns into an electron.

The $W^+$ is absorbed by the $d$ quark in the proton, which turns it into a $u$ quark.

One of the many virtual gluons around in the proton splits to become a $d$ and a $\overline d$.

The 4 quarks and the antiquark arrange themselves into $p$ and a $\pi^+$.

I don't have a drawing packing handy to show this but hopefully that's enough information for you to do it.